# List ALL users of GCP account/Organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have an organization in GCP with multiple projects in it.

Is there any way to list ALL project users and their roles without having to access project by project?

I was using `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECTNAME`, but list users for a single project, and I have a few hundreds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command in the Cloud Shell to fetch all projects and then show the iam-policy for each of them:

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list |  sed 1d | cut -f1 -d$' '); do 
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i;
done;
```

A few clarifications about the command:

- `sed 1d` removes the first row which will contain the following headers:

  `PROJECT_ID | NAME | PROJECT_NUMBER`
- `cut -f1 -d$' '` will fetch the first column, which is the PROJECT_ID that will be passed to the `gcloud projects get-iam-policy` command

## EDIT

As you wanted to get the results in a `PROJECT | MEMBERS | ROLE` style, you can use the following which will create a `.csv` file for each project with the following structure inside: `ROLES | MEMBERS`. Each fille will be named `PROJECT_ID.csv`

- Roles: Current role owned by the followed list of members
- Members: List of members who own the role

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list |  sed 1d | cut -f1 -d$' '); do
    echo "Getting IAM policies for project:" $i;
    echo "..........";
    (echo "ROLES,MEMBERS" && paste -d "," <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].role' | cut -d "\"" -f2)") <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].members | join(",")' | cut -d"\"" -f2)")) | cat >> $i.csv
 
    echo "Done. Logs created at file" $i.csv;
    echo "--------------------------------"
done;
```

The only requirement that may be needed to install here is `yq`, which you can install in your shell.

## EDIT 2:

As requested in the comments, all the information output will go to the same `.csv` file following the format: `PROJECT_ID | ROLE | MEMBERS`

```
echo "PROJECT_ID,ROLES,MEMBERS" | cat >> output.csv
for i in $(gcloud projects list |  sed 1d | cut -f1 -d$' '); do
    echo "Getting IAM policies for project:" $i;
    echo "..........";
    paste -d "," <(printf %s "$(for j in $(seq 1 $(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].role' | cut -d "\"" -f2 | wc -l)); do echo $i; done;)") <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].role' | cut -d "\"" -f2)") <(printf %s "$(gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i | yq '.bindings | .[].members | join(",")' | cut -d"\"" -f2)") | cat >> output.csv
 
    echo "Done. Logs created at file" $output.csv;
    echo "--------------------------------"
done;
```

Comment: This is Amazing. Thanks a lot.
Is there any way to sort the results in columns like ie:
Project ID | Members | Role
 
etc?
Thanks again

Comment: @FearF Thanks for approving my answer! I have also edited my answer to see if it better fits your needs, check it out and let me know!

Comment: Hi.
It does create the files, but i get this message:
Getting IAM policies for project: cake
..........
2019/09/05 14:27:07 unknown command ".bindings | .[].role" for "yq"
2019/09/05 14:27:07 unknown command ".bindings | .[].members | join(\",\")" for "yq"
Done. Logs created at file cake.csv

The file is has no usable data, only the error message.

Comment: You are missing the `yq` command probably? You can refer to this [link](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) where you have more info on how to install, it should work then.

Comment: Hi. I do have yq installed. But the message remains :( .
MacBook-Pro:~ fede$ yq --version
yq version 2.4.0

Comment: It is weird, I just have run the command and it works perfectly fine for me, the only difference I see is that i am using yq 2.7.2, that may be what's causing the problem

Comment: That seems to be the latest version for OSX.  Do you know any other way? I can display them and later on export them from the console. No a real need to print them as CSV.
Ps. I see that you are also in BCN.

Comment: can you try running `pip install pip --upgrade` and see if it manages to upgrade the `yq` command?

Comment: After installing pip and jq (not installed by default on osx) its running very nicely..
Again, Amazing !!
If you are looking for a change of air, contact me im looking for a linux admin, with cloud expertise in our area.

Ps- Is there any way to get all the data in a single file?

Comment: HI. If you have a min, is it possible to get the results in a single file? Thanks

Comment: Working on it, will update my answer as soon as I have it! :)

Comment: I have just updated my answer @FearF, you can check the solution in the 2 edit.

Comment: HI. It works perfect, it displays all the required data! Thanks a lot.

Comment: seems the latest yq version: 3.4.1 broke did not compatible with previous command line option...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to list ALL project users and their roles without
>   having to access project by project?

No, you will need to scan organizations, folders, projects, and resources to obtain a complete list of all IAM members with access to cloud resources. Scanning just projects will not give you a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to search all the IAM policies for organizations/folders/projects within your org:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="resource:*//cloudresourcemanager*"
```

You can change the scope to a folder or a project.

You must have the cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies permission upon the scope.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

It doesn't cover all the policies though: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Cloud Shell CLI changed default output (I'm using Google Cloud SDK 406.0.0), I had to craft own script to be able to get a CSV with all accounts in all projects for review in a spreadsheet editor:

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list --format="table(projectId)" | cut -f2 -d$' ' |  sed '/^$/d'); do 
    echo "Project $i,";
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy $i --flatten="bindings[].members[]" --format="csv[no-heading](bindings.members,bindings.role)";
done;
```