# GCP: How do I review IAM policy accross all my projects within organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to get the same results as with:

`$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy`

but on more than one project at a time?

Specifically on all projects in my organization

I tried

`$ gcloud organizations get-iam-policy ORGANIZATION_ID | grep user\: | sort | uniq`

but it only works on the users that have org level permissions assigned.
I am looking for a list of all users within organization with any project or even resource permissions assigned.

Comment: You want to extract roles on all user and on all project in the organisation? Without any filter on service/product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, it's not possible and the private alpha that I'm testing require to fill a role or an email or a resource to scan. Not a wide search like that you want.

You have to script this by yourselves. Make a loop over the projects, and call the get-iam-policy on each project. Something like this

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list | cut -d' ' -f1); do
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${i} | grep user\:  >> out
done

cat out | sort | uniq > out
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an official way to list all IAM policies within your organization yet, you can find a detailed way to do that and some examples in this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785783/list-all-users-of-gcp-account-organization).

Basically first you need to get the list of project IDs and then get the IAM-policy for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to search all the IAM policies for organizations/folders/projects within your org:

```
gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=organizations/123 --query="resource:*//cloudresourcemanager*"
```

You can change the scope to a folder or a project.

You must have the cloudasset.assets.searchAllIamPolicies permission upon the scope.

Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-iam-policies

It doesn't cover all the policies though: https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types